# Tailwind CSS: Navigation links and icon not centered when cart button is hidden

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I am using Tailwind CSS to create a header for my website. The header contains navigation links (Home, Store, and About) and a cart button. I want the navigation links and icon to be centered, regardless of whether the cart button is present or not.

I have tried adding the justify-center class to the nav element, but this does not center the navigation links and icon when the cart button is hidden. I have also tried adding the mx-auto class to the cart button, but this does not prevent the icon from moving when the button is hidden.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import Cart from "./Cart";
import { CartContext } from "../contexts/CartContext";

const Header = () => {
  const [isCartOpen, setIsCartOpen] = useState(false);
  const { cartElements } = useContext(CartContext);

  const toggleCart = () => {
    setIsCartOpen(!isCartOpen);
  };

  const location = useLocation();
  const isCartButtonHidden =
    location.pathname === "/home" || location.pathname === "/about";

  return (
    <header className="text-gray-600 body-font">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
        <a
          className="flex title-font font-medium items-center text-gray-900 mb-4 md:mb-0"
          href="www.google.co.in"
        >
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            className="w-10 h-10 text-white p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            <path d="M12 2L2 7l10 5 10-5-10-5zM2 17l10 5 10-5M2 12l10 5 10-5"></path>
          </svg>
          <span className="ml-3 text-xl">The Generics</span>
        </a>
        <nav className="md:ml-auto md:mr-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center">
          <Link className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" to="/home">
            Home
          </Link>
          <Link className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" to="/">
            Store
          </Link>
          <Link className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" to="/about">
            About
          </Link>
        </nav>
        {!isCartButtonHidden && (
          <button
            onClick={toggleCart}
            className="inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
          >
            {/* Display the number of items in the cart */}
            Cart
            <span class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-4 h-4 ml-2 text-xs font-semibold text-blue-800 bg-blue-200 rounded-full">
              {cartElements.length}
            </span>
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
      {isCartOpen && (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-50 z-50 ">
          <button
            onClick={toggleCart}
            className="absolute top-0 right-0 p-4 text-red-500 bg-transparent hover:bg-red-500 hover:text-white"
          >
            ❌
          </button>
          {/* <div className="pointer-events-none"> */}
          <Cart className="pointer-events-auto" />
        </div>
        // </div>
      )}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

How can I center the navigation links and icon, regardless of whether the cart button is present or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav className="md:ml-auto md:mr-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center">
      <Link className="mr-5 flex items-center justify-center hover:text-gray-900" to="/home">
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link className="mr-5 flex items-center justify-center hover:text-gray-900" to="/">
        Store
      </Link>
      <Link className="mr-5 flex items-center justify-center hover:text-gray-900" to="/about">
        About
      </Link>
    </nav>
```

To center a item inside a div using flex, item-center, justify-center. I do not know if there are better way but this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but, I don't wish it to be centred exactly in the given space. For example, consider a row of three blocks, and I want to make the rightmost box appear or disappear. With this code, the other two blocks also shift to the right. However, I want them to be stationary, whether the rightmost box is present or not. In my code, the rightmost box is the cart icon, and the other two blocks are links and an icon.